# How to make state consistency while using Action Cable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, actioncable

Let's assume we use something like current_user which is an instance of a ServiceClass which holds user model, session params and other info. 
The thing is that variable is being set during connection with websocket and being reused for all AC calls on *different* subscriptions.

Then, at some point user decides to update his username, we make a call to current_user.update(new_username) and it works okay.

But other AC subscriptions under that user still use old user model. I suppose as each subscription works under their own thread, thus updating user model under one thread will not update them under other threads. What is the best approach for such case?

```
class ServiceClass

def initialize(session,...)
  @session = session
  @user = current_user
end

 def update!(username)
  @user.username = username
  @user.save!
 end

 ...
end

module ApplicationCable
    class Channel < ActionCable::Channel::Base
      def current_user
        @current_user ||= ServiceClass.new(session, user)
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to broadcast to current_user and for current_user to be subscribed to his / her stream.

In your controller:

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast "#{current_user}"
```

In your channel (eg. app/channels/user_channel.rb)

```
class UserChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel  
  def subscribed
    stream_from "#{current_user}"
  end
end
```